# Angular: Error when calling function from parent component

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-components

I am trying to call a function of a child component from the parent component in my angular app but I'm getting an error

In my parent component (called the `slices` component) the child is the snd-canvas component here:

```
<snd-canvas #yourChild 
    *ngIf="isCanvasOpen" 
    [selectedSlice]="selectedSlice" 
    [parentComponent]="parentComponent">
</snd-canvas>
```

There is also a button in the parent component which I want to call the saveSlice() function that is in the child component:

```
<div *ngIf="!showSearchBar && isCanvasOpen">
    <button mat-icon-button 
        matTooltip="Save Slice" 
        (click)="yourChild.saveSlice()">
                ...icon...
    </button>
</div>
```

In the slice.component.ts I have

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
@ViewChild('yourChild') child;
```

However when I click the button I get the following error:

```
ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'saveSlice' of undefined
```

I believe the issue might be that when the slices component loads isCanvasOpen is initialized as false and thus the `snd-canvas` component isn't rendered yet and is undefined. I tried changing the `*ngIf="isCanvasOpen"` to `[hidden]="isCanvasOpen"` that fixed that error but caused a bunch of issue with the child with the NgInit function and other functions running out of order.  How can I fix this?

Comment: is `@ViewChild('yourChild') child;` a property of a Component class?

Comment: Yes, its defined like this:

    `export class SlicesComponent implements OnInit{
        @ViewChild('yourChild') child;
        ....rest of code....
    }`

Comment: Did you try `(click)="child.saveSlice()"`. Notice it should not be `yourChild` instead it should be `child`

Comment: Thank you @user2216584 that fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

in order to control the function from your child component on the parent component, you need to use output to achieve that.
For example you have

Assuming this is the function of your child view i.e html

```
<div (click)="saveAll()></div>
```

then in the child component import Event Emitter from angular core

```
import { Component, OnInit, Output, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';
```

now after the export class write this.

```
@Output() saveData: EventEmitter<any>; // An output event emitter variable

constructor() {
    this.saveData = new EventEmitter<any>(); // instantiate the Event Emitter
}

saveAll() {
    this.saveData.emit('') // Pass the object of the data you want to save or alter, could be a string or anything depending on the type assigned to the EventEmitter
}
```

Then in your parent view add edit this code and add the output

```
<snd-canvas #yourChild 
        *ngIf="isCanvasOpen" 
        [selectedSlice]="selectedSlice" 
        [parentComponent]="parentComponent"
        (saveData)="saveData($event)">
```

At this point you have your function, simple call the function in your parent component

```
saveData(res) {
console.log(res); // You can console log it to see the passed data
}
```

That will get it done.

Comment: Although this is a good recommendation, but it's not what OP asked about

Answer (score 0):

## slices.component.html (parent)

```
           <snd-canvas #yourChild 
                        *ngIf="isCanvasOpen" 
                        [selectedSlice]="selectedSlice" 
                        [parentComponent]="parentComponent">
            </snd-canvas>

    <div *ngIf="!showSearchBar && isCanvasOpen">
        <button mat-icon-button 
                matTooltip="Save Slice" 
                (click)="CallsaveSlice()">
// CallsaveSlice() method can be called when *ngIf is true and the element will // exists in dom
                   ...icon...
        </button>
    </div>
```

## slices.component.ts(parent)

```
@ViewChild('yourChild') child;

CallsaveSlice(){

    this.child.saveSlice();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it was a very simple solution, I just had to change `(click)="yourChild.saveSlice()"` to `(click)="child.saveSlice()"`.

Comment: I have showed this in my solution, above.Hope it helped.